# Reversing Markdown for bootstrap pagedown Textarea Editing

Tags: javascript, pagedown

I am using bootstrap pagedown editor. I am able to get the content and save it to database.

I saved in database as below.

```
  <p>cxcxcxcxcxcxcx</p>

  <p>cxcxcxcxcxcxcxcxcxcx</p>

  <p>cxcxcxcxcxcxcxcxcxcx</p>
```

For editing , i tried to display the content retrieved from my database in pagedown editor. It is displaying as below.

```
    <p>cxcxcxcxcxcxcx</p>

    <p>cxcxcxcxcxcxcxcxcxcx</p>

    <p>cxcxcxcxcxcxcxcxcxcx</p>
```

How to display this as plaintext?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `strip_tags()` for this,

```
echo strip_tags("your content.");
```

See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_string_strip_tags), `<b></b>` is getting removed there.

In case , if you want to remove paragraph(p) tags alone, you can check the below code.

```
     $tags_to_strip = array("p"); 

     foreach ($tags_to_strip as $tag) { 
         $txt = preg_replace("/<\\/?" . $tag . "(.|\\s)*?>/", '', $txt; 
     }
```

Comment: that's great. it worked out. i was searching for some solution using that editor functions itself, but couldn't find any. Anyways , thanks as this solved my issue.

Comment: Thanks, how to remove only <p>content</p> alone, how to remove only p tags and retain the content as it is. There are other tags as well in the content which will also be removed if i use strip_tags

Comment: you want to remove all <p> tags??

Comment: I was able to remove only <p> tags using this code. $tags_to_strip = array("p");
        foreach ($tags_to_strip as $tag) {
            $txt = preg_replace("/<\\/?" . $tag . "(.|\\s)*?>/", '', $txt;
        }

Comment: your issue is solved now?? please edit my answer with what you have found not. It might help others.

Comment: In case, if we can achieve using bootstrap pagedown editor, if anyone is aware about that please provide the sample code.